# why the first call to EXTERNAL WCFis very slow (20 seconds) only in windows server 2008?

Tags: wcf

I have an external WCF well work from the second call, the first is very slow takes  20 seconds.

My web.config

https://drive.google.com/a/integrens.com/file/d/0B8Ix7-GIED4eUVdNOTNYN215RVU/view?usp=sharing

My code

```
string mensaje = "";
mensaje = DateTime.Now.ToString();

System.Net.ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = true;
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
System.Net.ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = true;
EnvioSunat.billServiceClient obj = new EnvioSunat.billServiceClient();
//ASMX.billService obj = new ASMX.billService();
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ws_integrensfe\FacturaElectronica\20566598389-REDDIGITALDELPERUS.A.C\DocumentosElectronico\20566598389-01-FT01-00000012\20566598389-01-FT01-00000012.zip");
//obj.Open();                
var datarpta = obj.sendBill("20566598389-01-FT01-00000012.zip", data);
//obj.Close();
mensaje = mensaje + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString();
Label1.Text = mensaje;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859832/why-is-the-first-wcf-client-call-slow

Comment: In what circumstances does it **not** take 20 seconds for the first call to respond?

Comment: only happens when I is deployed on Windows Server 2008 R2 because the Windows 7 takes about 3 seconds.. any ideas?

Comment: @trifolius did you find a solution to this issue? I have experienced the same issue whereby the first call from a windows server 2008 client is very slow (15 to 20 seconds) vs windows server 2012 client taking < 5 seconds.